# I need the updated sum from 1st to the current date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have extracted the cell address of the current date by using:

```
=CELL("Address",INDEX($H$4:$AK$4,MATCH(G3,H4:$AK$4,1)))
```

`G3` contains the day number of the month.

Now I need to use the `Sum` formula in `G6` such that it adds the values from 1st to the current date which is updated by the function `Today()` in cell `G1`.

Is there a way I can use the `Sum` function to use the address inside the cell rather than the address of the cell.

[image: SS of the sheet]

You can download the sheet from [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U0FZGafKfVbNePqNDY0NWhzXIh7V6hVz/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=111361633898460177067&rtpof=true&sd=true).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are making it too difficult. Just use `SUMIF`, and make the criteria that the dates are less than today.

`=SUMIF(date_range, "<"&TODAY(), sum_range)`

Comment: Oh! oh, oh. You're on point. Thanks, I really was making this way too hard for myself.

Comment: @SameedIrfan If it solve your problem then accept the answer.